# Legal Recourse for Unfair Grading Based on Unverified AI Classification Results

Tags: education, artificial-intelligence

Can a student pursue legal action against an educational institution for grading them unfairly based on unverified AI classification results? Considering the inherent limitations of AI classifiers and the subjective nature of writing styles, where certainty of AI generation is unattainable, is there a legal basis for challenging such grading practices? Additionally, given the variability and unreliability of AI classifiers, could an institution’s reliance on such technology be considered negligent, especially in light of instances where even reputable platforms like OpenAI have discontinued their classifiers due to poor performance?

Comment: There's a very good chance your contract with the school enables them to change things like grading techniques and styles any time they want to. Public or private school? What state/country?

Answer (score 3):

In the [european-union](/questions/tagged/european-union), AI regulations are [prohibiting](https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations/dealing-citizens/are-there-restrictions-use-automated-decision-making_en) purely automated decisionmaking on matters significantly impacting people. The typical examples are commercial, like loan decisions based purely on an algorithm, but *fully* automatic grading might be problematic as well.

I do not know the case law on that, and anyway I cannot give legal advice. If you are thinking about a lawsuit, consider talking to organized student bodies at your university first.